# Differentiating expectation by a measure

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, derivatives

Consider the following expression:

$$
 \frac{d\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f(x)]}{d\mu} = \frac{d\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x)d\mu}{d\mu}
$$

where $x \in \mathcal{X}$ is the universal set associated with $\mu$. How do I evaluate this derivative? Defining the measure

$$\nu(A, \mu) = \int_{A}f(x)d\mu$$

We can rewrite this further as

$$\frac{d\nu(\mathcal{X}, \mu)}{d\mu}$$

As a result it seems reasonable for the derivative to be related to the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$, but I am struggling to make this connection explicit. To be honest I am kind of unclear on what is meant when one differentiates by a measure in this fashion, and would appreciate an explanation as to what is typically meant mathematically when one writes the original expression above where one differentiates an expectation by its corresponding measure.

EDIT: I guess the Radon-Nikodym derivative is $f$ in this case.

The paper I am reading is this:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.00177.pdf

In particular, the measure $\mu$ is a randomised policy $\pi$ over a Markov chain.

As mentioned in the comments, the I in fact wanted to compute the derivative with respect to the density function $g$ associated with $\mu$.

$$
 \frac{d\mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f(x)g(x)]}{dg} = \frac{d\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x)g(x)dx}{dg}
$$

The term I am differentiating seems to be linear in $g$. As a result, I would expect the derivative to be a constant. My assumption is that the derivative is simply $f$, as in terms of the normed space of continuous functions, we can write:
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int f(x)g(x) dx
$$
Naturally we would expect
$$
\frac{d\langle f, g \rangle}{dg} = f
$$

Thanks to everyone for the discussion in the comments. I will leave this question up in case someone makes the same mistake as myself (mistaking a measure for a density when differentiating).

Comment: Where have you found this? You can post references in an edit.

Comment: the map $\mu \mapsto \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f]$ is not a measure, so your question doesn't make sense as stated

Comment: Are you sure the $\mu$ in your expression is supposed to be a measure and not just a parameter in a parametrised family of measures?
 Say you're working with the measure $\mathcal{N}(\mu,1)$, then $d \mathbb{E}_{\mu} f(x)/d\mu$ would be the $\mu$ derivative of the ordinary, real-valued function $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \exp(-(\mu-x)^2/2)\textrm{d}x$.

Comment: @Snoop  The paper is here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.00177.pdf appendix A is where you can find the statement.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou so in the paper I am reading $\mu$ is a policy over a Markov chain. That is $\mu$ = $\pi(\cdot | s)$ where $\pi(a, s)$ is the probability of choosing policy $a$ in state $s$ according to the policy $\pi$.

Comment: @Masacroso So i can’t differentiate $g(\mu, f) = \mathbb{E}_{\mu}[f]$ by $\mu$? Can’t $g$ be viewed as a function of both $\mu$ and $f$? In this case why isn’t differentiation by $\mu$ possible?

Comment: I guess the derivative is taken in a kind of Frechet sense. We differentiate with respect to the function $\pi$.

Comment: @zhoraster If the policy is randomised then it is no longer a function though right? That is the policy itself may be a randomised mapping.

Comment: Now, it is a classical function (probability density) precisely because of randomization. Otherwize it would be a "delta" function.

Comment: @zhoraster so you are saying $\pi$ is a density? I guess my mistake was in thinking that $\pi$ was a distribution function (defined on the power set of $\mathcal{X}$) rather than a density function.

Comment: Yes, I am saying that. See e.g. equation (29) in the article.

Comment: @zhoraster I see thank you, I will give this problem a go with this definition in mind